# Max number of tables (objects) in SQL Server editions (compact, express)

Tags: sql-server, express-edition

What are the maximum number of tables that you can have in:

- SQL CE4
- SQL 2008 R2 Express

Numbers here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx I guess is for SQL Server 2008, but are they valid for Express and what about SQL CE4?

> The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647

Comment: SQL CE docs don't tell you. I'd suggest it's enough for your needs anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacity specifications are valid for Express apart from the limitations listed in:

- [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)
- [Maximum Number of Processors Supported by the Editions of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx) (max 1 cpu)
- [Memory Supported by the Editions of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685.aspx) (max  1GB ram)

So yes, the maximum number of tables is limited by the 2,147,483,647 object maximum in Express.

[Compact Edition differs substantially from Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx), with very different [capacity specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx). Haven't found an explicit reference to the maximum table or object count in CE but the 4GB size limit would prevent you getting anywhere near 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 1):

For SQLCe4, I got the response:

> There is no limit on number of tables, but we do have a limit of 4GB
>   file size.

//Daniel